# Intercepting HTTP Requests in Redux

Tags: redux

Many redux examples show making HTTP requests directly in an async action; however this will result in an exterme amount of duplicate code common to all requests, for example:

- Retrying failed requests based on status code
- Appending common HTTP Headers to each request.
- Invoking additional http requests based on response (ie: oauth token refresh)
- Aborting in-flight requests on route transitions.

My gut feeling is that a middleware could be used to make http requests (in the same vein as [`redux-api-middleware`](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware)) which can keep the in-flight requests in the `store` - however I am also wondering if I'm leaning on bad habbits - is a little duplication a small price to pay for immutability?

Answer (score 8):

Your action creators are just JavaScript functions.

If you have duplication between several functions, you extract the common code into another function. This is no different. Instead of duplicating the code, extract the common code into a function and call it from your action creator.

Finally, this pattern can be abstracted away with a custom middleware. Check out the “real world” example in Redux repo to see how it can be done.

Comment: Appreciated Dan (thanks for your great community work).

Answer (score 2):

All but the aborting could be accomplished while staying immutable by using a request factory which attaches `.then` and `.catch` (or equivalent, depending on promise flavor) to the request before returning it.

Comment: Thanks!  A requestFactory is an approach that I'm currently leaning on but I'm having difficulty keeping it stateless when it comes to replaying failed requests.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a action which executes its operation in addition it calls another action, to achieve this you need to have a [redux-async-transitions](https://github.com/Cron-J/redux-async-transitions), the example code is given below

```
function action1() {
 return {
  type: types.SOMEFUNCTION,
  payload: {
   data: somedata
  },
  meta: {
   transition: () => ({
    func: () => {
     return action2;
    },
    path : '/somePath',
    query: {
     someKey: 'someQuery'
    },
    state: {
     stateObject: stateData
    }
   })
  }
 }
}
```

and here is for asynchronous call

```
function asynccall() {
 return {
  types: [types.PENDINGFUNCTION, types.SUCCESSFUNCTION, types.FAILUREFUNCTION],
  payload: {
   response: someapi.asyncall() // only return promise
  }
  meta: {
   transition: (state, action) => ({
    onPending: () => {
    },
    onSuccess: (successdata) => {
     //gets response data can trigger result based on data
    },
    onFail: (promiseError) => {
     //gets error information used to display messages
    }
   })
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling http request in middleware is the same bad ideas as calling it in action creators. You should focus on making our reducers powerful enough to handle asynchronous effects as well as synchronous state transitions. The best way i found while working with redux is describe effects in the reducer(http request is the effect) and then handle it with library like [redux-loop](https://github.com/raisemarketplace/redux-loop) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga)

For avoiding code duplication you can extract common code to request function and use it for handling http effects